# How to display .gz files in browser (lighttpd)

Tags: lighttpd

I am trying to see compressed log in browser (lighttpd configuration).

But yet i am unable to uncompress those files.

Any idea?

```
".gz"  => "text/html",
```

Enables us to open file in html but not in readable format.

And another thing is: my final files are .gz.34534534 (random numbers) so i was looking forward to open these files in browser in order to read logs conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the file has '\n' or '\r\n'. you need to convert these to 
 when you display HTML, as line break elements are respected, but newlines are not. This can be done via a simple javascript replacement.

```
.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
```

on the data element value is what you are probably looking to use in this case.

This could also be done server-side, but formatting this client side seems easier imo.

You could also wrap the whole thing in a set of pre tags as well.